# I can't find a list of tweet that contains a specific word c# linqtotwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, find, cpu-word

I have to find a list of tweet that contains a specific word giving by the user.
I didn't find the specific function to do this.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
 public List<Status> TrouverMot()
        {
            var srch =
                (from search in MainPage.twitterCtxProp.Status         //a voir!
                 where search.Type ==StatusType.User &&
                       search.Text.Contains(MainPage.texte)
                 select search).ToList();
            List<Status> liste = new List<Status>();
            liste = srch;

            return liste;
        }
```

What can I do?

Comment: Well *how* does it not work?

Comment: why not to return (from search in MainPage.twitterCtxProp.Status where search.Type == StatusType.User && search.Text.Contains(MainPage.texte)
                 select search).Cast<Status>().ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method in the LinqToTwitter API : 
http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Searching%20Twitter&referringTitle=Performing%20Searches%20and%20Finding%20Trends